# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else (bbcode error on phpBB)

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

I'm using phpBB as my forum and I want  to implement a spoiler tag. I have searched online on how to implement this custom bbcode and I always find the same code:

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 2px;">
<b>Spoiler! </b>
<input value="Show" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; width: 60px; font-size: 10px;" onclick="if(this1.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != 'inline') { this1.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'inline'; this.innerText = ''; this.value = 'Hide'; }else{ this1.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; this.innerText = ''; this.value='Show'; }" type="button"> </div>
<div style="border: 1px inset; padding: 6px;">
<div style="display: none;">{TEXT}</div> </div>
```

However, in Chrome I get the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else", and in Firefox it says: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token else"

Does anybody know what gives the error?

Comment: Change `this1.parentNode` to `this.parentNode`

Comment: Doesn't work, I added that just to see if it would change the error message, I accidentally posted this instead of the right one.

Comment: @nikhil that may be necessary, but it wouldn't cause the syntax error.

Comment: @Pointy - I agree. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: That code is syntactically fine, so maybe something is screwing it up between the PHP source and the page. Use the browser "view source" or the debug console to see what the HTML actually looks like.

Comment: If you want to know where is error, put your "onclick" javascript code into the function:  ... onclick="somefunc()" Put this "somefunc()" into js file and debug it

Comment: @Pointy, when looking at the source code I can see that everything between { } accolades has been removed from the code so thats why I get the else error. Can I replace the accolades by something else?

Comment: No, unfortunately; that's JavaScript syntax.  I don't know enough about PHP or phpBB to suggest a way to prevent the source from being corrupted.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll report it to the phpBB team then as the error is probably caused by their software.